# Access - How to delete records if there is data with a newer date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to delete some records from access.  My data looks like,

```
RDNUMB | RD SEQ | COUNTDATE | COUNT
-------+--------+-----------+--------
101200 | 10     | 3/25/12   | 120
101200 | 20     | 2/27/13   | 1400
101200 | 20     | 6/15/11   | 905
101200 | 20     | 10/1/07   | 1020
```

I need to figure out a way to look at look at the RDNUMB and RD SEQ and delete the entire record if there are records with a newer date.  In this case I need to delete the records on dates 6/15/11 and 10/1/07. 
RD SEQ is not unique to only this RDNUMB it is used over and over again.
Thanks for your thoughts and time

Comment: [*Have you tried anything*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: ok, i think what i have would work, it definitely should work for SQL Server.  Access supports pretty much the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From a SQL Perspective this is what you want to do:

```
DELETE T
FROM YourTable AS T
JOIN (  SELECT RDNUMB, RDSEQ, COUNTDATE
        FROM YourTable AS YT
        WHERE YT.RDNUMB = T.RDNUMB AND YT.RDSEQ = T.RDSEQ
          AND YT.CountDate <> (SELECT MAX(COUNTDATE) FROM YourTable 
                               WHERE RDNUMB = YT.RDNUMB AND RDSEQ = YT.RDSEQ)
) AS R
  ON R.RDNUMB = T.RDNUMB AND R.RDSEQ = T.RDSEQ AND R.COUNTDATE = T.COUNTDATE
```

Comment: Thanks for your time T McKeown.  I tried what you suggested and I get the error, Syntax error in FROM clause.  This is what I have so far,

Comment: DELETE T 
FROM a1RolledData AS T
JOIN (SELECT a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR], a1RolledData.[RD SEQ], a1RolledData.[COUNT DATE]
         FROM a1RolledData AS YT

Comment: WHERE YT.a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] = T.a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] AND YT.a1RolledData.[RD SEQ]
         AND YT.a1RolledData.[COUNT DATE] <> (SELECT MAX(a1RolledData.[COUNT DATE]) FROM a1RolledData
                                                      WHERE a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] = YT.a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] AND a1RolledData.[RD SEQ] = YT.a1RolledData.[RD SEQ])
AS R
ON R.a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] = T.a1RolledData.[ROAD NBR] AND R.a1RolledData.[RD SEQ] AND R.COUNTDATE = T.a1RolledData.[COUNT DATE];

Comment: I pulled the data into a sql database and getting errors...... 1.  The multi-part identifier "T.ROAD NBR" could not be bound...  2.  An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.This is at the YT.[RDSEQ]... 3.  Incorrect syntax near 'AS'  at the AS R

Comment: If you are specifying columns like "T.Road Nbr" with a space in it you need to wrap brackets, use T.[Road Nbr] instead.

Comment: not sure why the JOIN ( SELECT ..... ) AS R would complain, you sure you have balanced parens?\

Comment: I have the brackets.  This is my line, WHERE YT.[ROAD NBR] = T.[ROAD NBR] AND YT.[RD SEQ] I get the multi-part identifier could not be bound on the T.[ROADNBR] AND An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected  on the YT.[RD SEQ]

Comment: As for the AS R issue you were correct.  I was missing a paren.

Comment: according to your posting, it should be `WHERE YT.[RDNUMB] = T.[RDNUMB] AND YT.[RD SEQ] = T.[RD SEQ]`  I am assuming these column names are correct, only you will know if they are correct.  Your post has columns listed as [RDNUMB], [RD SEQ] no sure why you are now using [ROAD NBR]